# Python, Import config.py

Tags: python, python-import

```
# config.py
white = (255,255,255)

# main.py
import config
print(white)

# output:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\...\Test\Test2.py", line 2, in <module>
    print(white)
NameError: name 'white' is not defined

Process finished with exit code 1

# wanted output
(255, 255, 255)
 
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Hello

I want to create a variable in a config.py file, import that file into main.py, and use the variable. But the variable does not become available in main.py. I don't want to change the variable inside main.py, I only want to reference to it. What am I doing wrong?

The code provided is a simplification of the actual code and acts as an example.

One solution I can find is the following. But what shall I do if I have got multiple variables?

```
# main.py
import config
white_new = config.white
print(white_new)
```

Comment: `import config.py` would raise an error. Please **always provide a [mcve]** But assuming you actually did `import config`, then **why did you expect** to be able to `print(white)`? You would need to use `config.white`. Which is probably what you should use

Comment: "But what shall I do if I have got multiple variables?" you *should* just use `config.whatever`. You *could* also use a `from config import <list of variable>` or even `from config import *`, but the latter is considered a bad practice. Really, just using `import config` and `config.white`, `config.yellow` or whatever is the best way

Comment: Your solution is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do:

```
# main.py
from config import white
print(white)
```

For multiple variables:

```
from config import white, variable_1, variable_2, ...
```